# Outlook Add-in: Knowing how long user has been composing email

Tags: outlook-web-addins

In my time-tracking add-in I need to know how long the user has been writing his email. For the READ mode there is dateTimeCreated. But that field does not exist in COMPOSE mode.

What I want:

1. User writes his email
2. Before he sends it, he opens the add-in taskpane. The add-in automatically calculates the time the user has been composing the email and shows this time on the screen: like

`var time = new Date() - Office.context.mailbox.item.dateTimeCreated`

This won't work obviously because `dateTimeCreated` does not exist in the compose mode, but just so you get the idea...

Any idea on how to achieve this? Some alternatives?

Comment: This may help store some date/time information, all the different ways to persist info in Outlook Apps, but you may also have some options with HTML5 local storage...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings

Comment: To get the time when the message was first created, without your addin being opened, you will need an API. Currently an API to get datetime when the email is created, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook automatically creates a Draft of any email after a set amount of time. You could set the "automatically save draft" setting to 1 second, then your timer can be based on the time the draft email was created.

Comment: Thats actuallly a pretty slick idea... Why didn't I come up with that?
It's a bit of work, and you need the read/write/mailbox permission, but it should be possible that way...